# Swift - Realm , completion after successfully adding item

Tags: ios, swift, realm

So i have this code that meant to add items into the realm:

```
static func insertAsynctTest(_ objects: [Object], success: @escaping () -> Void, failure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        autoreleasepool {
            if let realm = getInstance() {
                do {
                    try realm.write {
                        for object in objects {
                            realm.add(object, update: .modified)
                        }
                        success()
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Something went wrong: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    failure()
                }
            }
            failure()
        }
    }
}
```

The closure is a must because  i need to know that the action is done.
What happens now is that i don't know if the realm finished adding in his thread, so the  success() is  a false because the loop finished but the adding isn't , and when i try to fetch the data after i am crushing with the follow error:"Realm accessed from incorrect thread".
Is there a way to know that the adding is done?
Thanks

Comment: realm is not thread safe. "Realm accessed from incorrect thread" means you first initialized realm on a different thread and now you are trying to access realm on a different thread. You should always access realm on the thread that it is initialized first.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri so i need to access DispatchQueue.global()?

Comment: not always, as said, if you initialize realm in main thread first, you have to access realm only on main thread.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri So i think i got it.
Somewhere in the lifecycle of the app the realm instance is initialised in the main queue and thas why i cant ""touch it".
Sounds right?

Comment: yes, cant touch it on other threads other than main thread in that case

Comment: @TejaNandamuri thanks!
You can post an answer so i will choose it :)

Comment: While the accepted answer is generally correct. It may not be the best solution here. When you start working with *ThreadSafeReference* it can add additional complexity to the code. You may want to consider simpler route; just access Realm the same every time across your code. See [Realm Threading](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#passing-instances-across-threads). So for example, you could have a singleton that gives you access to Realm on a background thread (a common use case). So just use that same singleton throughout your app and the problem is solved.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri so i did the singletone solution that you offered , yet i  am still getting the error above

Comment: I didn't suggest the singleton approach. It will crash as long as you access the singleton on different threads. @ironRoei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm is not thread safe. "Realm accessed from incorrect thread" means you first initialized realm on a different thread and now you are trying to access realm on a different thread. You should always access realm on the thread that it is initialized first.

If you initialize realm in main thread first, you have to access realm only on main thread.

There is another approach to access realm across threads. It is by using `ThreadSafeReference`

```
//If you have a person initialized from a different thread, create a ThreadSafeReference for that object
let personRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: person)
```

Now you can use that object in any thread

```
DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.myApp.bg").async {
  let realm = try! Realm()
  guard let person = realm.resolve(personRef) else {
    return // person was deleted
  }
  try! realm.write {
    person.name = "Jane Doe"
  }
}
```

Please refer realm [documentation](https://realm.io/blog/obj-c-swift-2-2-thread-safe-reference-sort-properties-relationships/) on thread safety.